# Merging items in list given condition

Tags: python, list, algorithm

Let's say I have `['A B', 'B C', 'X Y', 'C D', 'Y Z', 'D E', 'C G']`.

If the second word in each element of the list is same as first word in any other elements in the list, they should be merged into one item. The order matters as well.

`['A B C D E G', 'X Y Z']` should be the final product.

Letters will not form a cycle, i.e., `['A B', 'B C', 'C A']` is not possible.

As for why `G` was added at the end, let's say we are at `'A B C'` and we see `'C D'`. And later on in the list we have `'C G'`. We add `'C D'` since it comes first, so we have `'A B C D'`, and then if there is `'D E'` we merge that to `'A B C D E'`. Now at the end of a 'chain', we add `'C G'` so we have `'A B C D E G'`. If there had been a `'B H'`, since `B` comes first, then it would be `'A B C D E H G'`.

Since order matters, `['A B', 'C A']` is still `['A B', 'C A']` since B does not connect to C.

Another example is:

If we have `['A B', 'A C']` then at step 1 we just have `A B` and then we see `A C` and we merge that into `A B` and we have `A B C`.

I have tried many things, such as dissecting each element into two lists, then indexing and removing etc. It is way too complex and I feel there should be a more intuitive way to solve this in Python. Alas, I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: plain BFS/DFS is sufficient

Comment: You should also mention in the post if for the same first element there are different second elements present. Say, 'C E' was also present.

Comment: Also, are you trying to maximize final product? or whatever product you return is good?

Comment: Also, Why E F is a part of the product without a connection with A B C D? Shouldn't it be seperate? Or something like 'D E' should be in the input.

Comment: Can you kindly let me know the answer to ['A B', 'B C', 'C A']. If I understand correctly, since 'A B' 'B C' should be together, 'B C' 'C A' should be together, 'C A' 'A B' should be together. So, all of them needs to be together. But, there is no way to maintain the ordering in the final answer if all of them are together. For example, if the final answer is ['A B C'] then it violates the order 'C A' as C should appear before A in the answer.

Comment: @NayeemulIslamSwad all elements should be unique. I will update this, thank you.

Comment: Err, I'm sorry if I'm being dumb, but I don't quite understand what you mean by "letters will not appear twice". In the example you provided in the post, `['A B', 'B C', 'X Y', 'C D', 'Y Z', 'D E', 'C G']`, several of the letters (for example B) is appearing twice.

But, I might have a solution to the ['A B', 'B C', 'C A'] situation for you. You might say that there can be no cyclic relationship between the letters. Since A->B->C->A creates a cycle, this case would then be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple algorithm solving this appears to be:

- initialize *results* as empty list
- repeat for each *pair* in input list:

  - repeat for each sublist *R* in *results*:

    - if *R* contains the first item of *pair*, append second item to *R* and continue with next pair
  - if no sublist *R* contained the first item of *pair*, append *pair* as new sublist to *results*

The implementation in Python is straightforward and should be self-explanatory:

```
def merge_pairs(pairs):
    results = []
    for pair in pairs:
        first, second = pair.split()
        for result in results:
            if first in result:
                result.append(second)
                break
        else:
            results.append([first, second])
    return [' '.join(result) for result in results]
```

The only extra steps are the conversions between space-separated letters and lists of letters by `.split()` and `' '.join()`.

Note the `else` clause of the `for` statement which is only executed if no `break` was encountered.

Some examples:

```
>>> merge_pairs(['A B', 'B C', 'X Y', 'C D', 'Y Z', 'D E', 'C G'])
['A B C D E G', 'X Y Z']
>>> merge_pairs(['A B', 'A C'])
['A B C']
>>> merge_pairs(['B C', 'A B'])
['B C', 'A B']
```

Answer (score 1):

bit messy but this works.

a = ['AB', 'BC', 'XY', 'CD', 'YZ', 'DE', 'CG']

```
used_item = []
result = []
for f, fword in enumerate(a):
    for s, sword in enumerate(a):
        if f == s:
            continue
        if fword[1] == sword[0]:
            if f in used_item or s in used_item:
                idx = [i for i, w in enumerate(result) if fword[1] in w][0]
                result = [r + sword[1] if i == idx else r for i, r in enumerate(result) ]  
                used_item.append(f)
                used_item.append(s)
          
          
            else:
                result.append(fword+sword[1])
                used_item.append(f)
                used_item.append(s)
                
print(result)
```

output is ['ABCDGE', 'XYZ']
you could sort 'ABCDGE' if necessary.

Comment: The output should be `['A B C D E G', 'X Y Z']` ... for e.g. we have  `'A B C'` and we see `'C D'` first in the list. Later on in the list we also have `'C G'`.

We add `'C D'` since it comes first in the list, so now we have `'A B C D'`, and then if there is `'D E'` we merge that to `'A B C D E'`. 

Now at the end of a 'chain', we add `'C G'` so we have `'A B C D E G'`. If there had been a `'B H'`, since `B` comes first, then it would be `'A B C D E H G'`.

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate all the above answers and wanted to attempt the question using **Graph Theory.**

This question is a classic example of **connected components**, where we can assign a `unique identifier` to each node (nodes are the different characters in the list = A, B, C, .... Z) accordingly.

Also, as we need to maintain the order, **DFS** is the correct choice to proceed with.

```
Algorithm:
    1. Treat the characters A, B, C, .... Z as different 26 nodes.
    2. Perform DFS on each node.
            2.1 If the node has not been assigned an unique identifier:
                    2.1.1. Assign a new unique identifier to the node.
                    2.1.2. dfs(node)
                    
            2.2 Else:
                    no nothing
```

The function `dfs()` will group the nodes according to the `unique identifier`. While performing **DFS**, the child gets the **same** `unique identifier` as its parent.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
class Graph:
    
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.number_of_nodes = n
        self.visited = []
        self.adjacency_list = []
        self.identifier = [-1] * self.number_of_nodes
        self.merged_list = []
    
    def add_edge(self, edge_start, edge_end):
        if(self.encode(edge_end) not in self.adjacency_list[self.encode(edge_start)]):
            self.adjacency_list[self.encode(edge_start)] = self.adjacency_list[self.encode(edge_start)] + [self.encode(edge_end)]
        
    def initialize_graph(self):
        self.visited = [False] * self.number_of_nodes
        for i in range(0, self.number_of_nodes):
            self.adjacency_list = self.adjacency_list + [[]]

    def get_adjacency_list(self):
        return self.adjacency_list

    def encode(self, node):
        return ord(node) - 65
    
    def decode(self, node):
        return chr(node + 65)
    
    def dfs(self, start_index):
    
        if(self.visited[self.encode(start_index)] == True):
            return
    
        self.visited[self.encode(start_index)] = True
        
        for node in self.adjacency_list[self.encode(start_index)]:
            
            if(self.identifier[node] == -1):
                self.identifier[node] = self.identifier[self.encode(start_index)]
            
            if(self.visited[node] == False):
                self.merged_list[self.identifier[node]] = self.merged_list[self.identifier[node]] + self.decode(node)
                
                self.dfs(self.decode(node))                

graph = Graph(26)
graph.initialize_graph()

input_list = ['A B', 'B C', 'X Y', 'C D', 'Y Z', 'D E', 'C G']

for inputs in input_list:
    edge = inputs.split()
    edge_start = edge[0]
    edge_end = edge[1]
    graph.add_edge(edge_start, edge_end)
    
unique_identifier = 0

for inputs in input_list:
    edge = inputs.split()
    edge_start = edge[0]
    
    if(graph.identifier[graph.encode(edge_start)] == -1):
        graph.identifier[graph.encode(edge_start)] = unique_identifier
        graph.merged_list = graph.merged_list + [edge_start]
        unique_identifier = unique_identifier + 1
        graph.dfs(edge_start)

print(graph.merged_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['ABCDEG', 'XYZ']
```